# NPAPI - use javascript objects/functions from within plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, npapi

I've read about how to obtain a handle on DOM elements.
This was a very helpful link: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=1521545

My question now is, can I get a handle on a Javascript var/object I've created, or arbitrary functions?

On page load, i have a script executing something like this...

```
var controller = new Controller()
```

or

```
function callme(param1, param2) { ... }
```

now, from within my plugin, I want to be able to call methods from my controller object. OR, execute that function callme.
Is this possible and how would I go about doing this?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your link you know how to get the NPObject for the DOM window; from there all you need to know is that all global javascript variables are actually properties of the window.

```
var controller = new Controller();
```

If you've done this in the global scope, then window.controller is your variable, so you just need to do:

```
/* Get window object */
NPObject* window = NULL;
NPN_GetValue(aInstance, NPNVWindowNPObject, &window);

/* Get document object */
NPVariant controllerVar;
NPIdentifier id = NPN_GetStringIdentifier("controller");
NPN_GetProperty(aInstance, window, id, &controllerVar);
NPObject* document = NPVARIANT_TO_OBJECT(controllerVar);
```

You can then access properties on your `Controller` object or call methods. Note that if controller were a function you could call it with `NPN_InvokeDefault`.

BTW, [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) automates most of this.

Comment: Great, thanks so much. I've read your blog and your 3-part plugin tutorial, but it appears it's my lack of DOM/javascript know-how that's in the way. I tried assuming the above was true, and used chrome's javascript console to list the window object's properties, but a different error was in the way that prevented my object from being a child of window. I appreciate the speedy response.